# How do I make Predict function accept a sequence of data inputs as a feature while training?

Tags: machine-learning

How do I make Predict function accept a sequence of data inputs as a feature while training? I am unable to use this :
trainingdata = { 5 -> {{1,4},{2,3}}, 6 ->  {{2,4},{3,3}} , .... }
as training data for Predict inbuilt function.

This is the code I tried.

```
trainingset = {4 -> {{1, 3}, {2, 2}}, 
5 -> {{2, 3}, {1, 4}}, 6 -> {{3, 3}, {1, 5}}, 
7 -> {{4, 3}, {2, 5}}};

p = Predict[trainingset, 
Method ->"LinearRegression"]
```

ERROR MSG : Predict::  Incompatible variable type (Numerical) and variable value ({{1,3},{2,2}}).

Comment: Can you show the entire code you have developed so far, including the call to Predict?

Comment: p = NetTrain[NetChain[{4, ReshapeLayer[{2, 2}]}, "Input" -> "Real"], trainingset] effectively does the same as what I guess you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you. This seems to work. Need to read more about these capabilities.